# Any problem if i will have only index.php instead of

Tags: php, dynamic

i am trying to create a website, a dynamic one.
i wanted to know if is any problem if i will not divide the index.php file, so it will have the header , footer, sidebar etc, in one file. is any thing wrong here? So instead having, header.php, index.php, footer.php, sidebar.php, i will create only index.php..

need some suggestions from experts please
Thank you for reading this post.

Comment: Thank you to all of you for the answer.
I am not an expert on this , is why i am asking.
I want to implement cache system later, but i dont want to cache the whole site, but only a file, for example, i want to cache only the posts, not the main page, and the sub pages. but the posts , so it will be the file single.php if i will put everything inside, but if i will separate them, what file should i cache ?

AvinD

Comment: Just implement (APC)[http://php.net/apc] and let it handle the details. it'll figure out which files are most commonly used and pin them into the cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's almost always a good idea to split things up this. My typical "simple" site layout has a header, a footer, and a body, each with its own files. It's rare for more than a couple pages to have different headers/footers, so almost every page ends up looking like:

```
<?php  include('header.inc'); ?>
body goes here
<?php include('footer.inc'); ?>
```

And the header/footer files boil down to `<html><body>` and `</body></html>` respectively (with all the usual css/javascript/meta/headers, etc... of course).

Nothing wrong with keeping everything in a single file, but then you'd have to hard-code your menus/sidebars/footers/headers/etc... into every PHP file.

Comment: Thank you to all of you for the answer. I am not an expert on this , is why i am asking. I want to implement cache system later, but i dont want to cache the whole site, but only a file, for example, i want to cache only the posts, not the main page, and the sub pages. but the posts , so it will be the file single.php if i will put everything inside, but if i will separate them, what file should i cache ?

Answer (score 1):

absolutely nothing wrong. well. at the start.

you'll have issues with maintainability of that single file later when it gets bit. *if* you're planning to grow big.

Answer (score 1):

No there is nothing wrong in that approach, it might be a pain to maintain though.

Answer (score 0):

You need not any additional files.
This files are used only for easy edit, more obvious struct and having main code in different pages

Answer (score 0):

I think it's great. Since your PHP-processor only needs to interpretet 1 file (instead of 4), it'll probably go a lot faster (when you are not using any OP code compiler).

Answer (score 0):

Segregating your code is good practice as it helps prevent duplicate code. Say you want page2.php and you need the same header, footer, sidebar, etc. Are you going to copy/paste in that code? Just make your template views like they're supposed to and piece together your structure for optimal code redundancy avoidance.

If you **NEVER** plan on scaling this project, one page is fine.

Comment: Thank you to all of you for the answer. I am not an expert on this , is why i am asking. I want to implement cache system later, but i dont want to cache the whole site, but only a file, for example, i want to cache only the posts, not the main page, and the sub pages. but the posts , so it will be the file single.php if i will put everything inside, but if i will separate them, what file should i cache ?

Comment: You can cache anything you would normally output to the browser. If you want to cache posts, you simply grab your posts from the database and then before you display them, you write them to a file called `posts_cache.html` or something to that effect. Next time you need to display posts, you simply check the current `time()` against the cache file's `filemtime()` (last modified time). If too much time has passed (you decide how long you want your posts cached), re-write the file with new posts, else, just include the file and make no database query for posts.

Answer (score 0):

While there is nothing wrong theoretically, this is by definition a bad practice.

By separating functional / organisational wholes into different files / classes / modules, you achieve decoupling and get a larger control level over your application, it will be much easier to maintain, you wont have to harcode and copy/paste much etc...

Why would you want to put all of your code into a single file?

Comment: Thank you to all of you for the answer. I am not an expert on this , is why i am asking. I want to implement cache system later, but i dont want to cache the whole site, but only a file, for example, i want to cache only the posts, not the main page, and the sub pages. but the posts , so it will be the file single.php if i will put everything inside, but if i will separate them, what file should i cache ?